# Data to plot graph in gremlin

Tags: gremlin

I am new to gremlin and  have a requirement to provide the data to plot a graph

Graph has

x axis -> timestamp
y-axis -> Sum of product

Below is the data in graph format

Nodes        relation(properties)                Nodes

userA       likes(timestamp = 22/02/2013)        productXY
 userX       likes(timestamp = 21/05/2013)        productAA
 userG       likes(timestamp = 22/07/2014)        productXB
 userT       likes(timestamp = 03/02/2013)        productXR
 userA       likes(timestamp = 22/02/2013)        productXT
 userC       likes(timestamp = 19/11/2014)        productUY
 userD       likes(timestamp = 22/07/2014)        productPY
 userE       likes(timestamp = 09/07/2013)        productLY
 userJ       likes(timestamp = 09/07/2013)        productXY
 userP       likes(timestamp = 09/07/2013)        productKY

Output of the query should be like this.

[09/07/2013, 3]
[22/02/2013, 2]
[21/05/2013, 1]
[22/07/2014, 2]
[03/02/2013, 1]
[19/11/2014, 1]

Could somebody help me in bulind the query.

Note: I have using Rexster RESTAPI to render the data to the application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the gremlin-users [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users):

Basically -

> you can use the [Gremlin extension](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki/Gremlin-Extension&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFyp4bZfOjaczG_XKsdclv5kV6Rtw) and this query:
>   g.V().outE("likes").timestamp.groupCount().cap().next()